# How to describe commutative rules in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I intend to describe "a rule is commutative" in my database, an immediate idea is that like the code.

```
certain_rule(X,Y) :- X = struct(_X,Others) , Y = some_process_base_on(_X).
certain_rule(Y,X) :- X = struct(_X,Others) , Y = some_process_base_on(_X).
```

But if `X` is unbound, it will make `X` bind with `struct(_X,Others)` directly, then `some_process_base_on(_X)` will be unknown. Now my solution is insert `compound(X)` before breakdown `X`.

Usually, `compound/1` is not strict enough, something unexpected will be taken in, `functor/3` may be a better solution but too many rules will exist since too many functors I need to compare, even if I use `member/2` to find functor in list I still construct too many combination.

Is there any better way to describe 'commutative', BTW, is there any better way to screen some specified structures out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your clauses are equivalent to writing:

```
certain_rule(struct(X,_), some_process_base_on(X)).
certain_rule(some_process_base_on(X), struct(X,_)).
```

A possible solution to **screen** for valid structures is to use a table of valid structures. For example:

```
valid_structure(-) :-
    !,
    fail.
valid_structure(struct(_,_)).
valid_structure(some_process_base_on(_)).
...
```

The first clause will screen out variables while preserving first-argument indexing for the predicate. You could then define a *gatekeeper* predicate:

```
certain_rule_gatekeeper(X, Y) :-
    once((valid_structure(X); valid_structure(Y))),
    certain_rule(X, Y).
```

To address **commutativity**, would a definition such as the following would work in your specific case?

```
certain_rule_gatekeeper(X, Y) :-
    once((valid_structure(X); valid_structure(Y))),
    once((certain_rule(X, Y); certain_rule(Y, X))).
```

Sample calls using just one of the clauses above for the `certain_rule/2` predicate (thus avoiding duplicated information):

```
| ?- certain_rule_gatekeeper(X, Y).               
no

| ?- certain_rule_gatekeeper(struct(X,_), Y). 
Y = some_process_base_on(X)
yes

| ?- certain_rule_gatekeeper(Y, struct(X,_)).
Y = some_process_base_on(X)
yes

| ?- certain_rule_gatekeeper(some_process_base_on(X), Y).
Y = struct(X,_)
yes

| ?- certain_rule_gatekeeper(Y, some_process_base_on(X)).
Y = struct(X,_)
yes
```

Comment: It was helpful for a lot, except that I need to call the rule to get some values, so commutativity in gatekeeper doesn't work, but base on the solution that implement screen by defining various valid_structure/1 facts have solved almost all the problem.Thanks very much.